# Jenkins build and the input prompt

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

so i have setup a jenkins build server on my unraid box running in a docker container.

This successfully spins up a docker container per build on pushes to master and tag creation of repositories.

i am filtering 3 tasks

staging deploys only run for master changes

uat deploys only run for tag creations

and then i have a task also for tag creations using input to block prod deploys until the user presses proceed.

This all works fine.

My question is, can i use input but have the pipeline finish or pause until the user has entered proceed/deny? As at the moment the docker container will just stay running as does the pipeline until the user has actioned the pipeline

Thanks!

Comment: You might have a look at this https://medium.com/disney-streaming/jenkins-pipeline-with-dynamic-user-input-9f340fb8d9e2, with the timeout option.

Comment: Thanks! that i think as close as im going to get to what im after. one issue though, if i "restart from step" for the "deploy to production step" it skips some required dependency steps. do you happen to know if there is a way to enforce build steps even when resuming?